# How to make dynamic ARC circle for Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-8

I am trying to make `XAML` / `C#` easily customizable and dynamic ARC circle for `Windows Phone 7.5` and `Windows 8`.

Lets imagine: I need basically a circle and then somehow I need to cut out a part, according to the parameter. So let's say 100% is full circle, and a 50% is half circle and etc.

I found an [example](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/12/colorful-clock-jquery-css/demo.html), what I want to make is exactly the same.

Can someone help me to accomplish this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use these links together with animation...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.aspx, http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/ralph/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5

Answer (score 3):

Try to use following code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardForArcAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Arc.EndAngle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arcRed" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:1:0" Value="360" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


 <local:Arc x:Name="arcRed"
                   ArcThickness="60"
                   ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel"
                   Fill="Red"
                   Height="300"
                   Width="300"
                   StartAngle="0"
                   EndAngle="10"
                   />
```

In code behind use StoryboardForArcAnimation.Begin() to start the animation.

You must add a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Drawing and add Namespace Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.Shapes (or Microsoft.Expression.Controls for Windows Phone 8)

Comment: What is local: Arc here? Can you edit and add that class also?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how to draw it. This is 1/4 of a circle.

```
               <Path Opacity="0" Visibility="Visible" Fill="{StaticResource AwesomenessBrush}" StrokeThickness="0">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="17 20">
                            <ArcSegment Point="20 17" Size="3 3" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                            <LineSegment Point="20 19"/>
                            <ArcSegment Point="19 20" Size="1 1"/>
                            <LineSegment Point="17 20"/>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
```

You can change the parameters from code.